# VBA Excel 2019: Turn Off Hyperlinks for Workbook for All Users When Opening

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a shared database of contacts with their email addresses and webpages but do not want them hyperlinked.  I have turned off AutoFormat for hyperlinks and removed them all from the workbook for myself but they pop up for other users.

Is there a way to turn-off Hyperlinks or AutoFormatting for them when other users open the workbook?

For another workbook, I have it auto-Enable Iterative Calculation when opened but not sure how or if it's possible to turnoff hyperlinking in the same manner?

```
Dim SaveIteration As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
SaveIteration = Application.Iteration
Application.Iteration = True
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.Iteration = SaveIteration

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [workbook open event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) to trigger a sub that loops though all worksheets, loop though all the sheets' links using the [hyperlinks object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlinks) then use the properties of the individual [hyperlink objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hyperlink) to do what you want. e.g. use the `Range` property and convert the link to plain text, delete it, whatever.